# Win32Exception: Parameter incorrect and Connection String is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with my asp.net mvc application, in my solution I have 3 projects (dll library project for my business layer, asp.net mvc for the website and console program for testing the business layer). When I try to login I get this exception:

```
    System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Paramètre incorrect
[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)]
```

Here's my code, Business Layer:

```
public BaseUser Authenticate(string User, string Password)
    {
        using(ASTBusinessLayerContext context = new ASTBusinessLayerContext())
        {
            BaseUser userExists = context.BaseUsers.Where(u => u.Creds.Login == User).First();
            if (userExists != null && HashingUtils.VerifyMd5Hash(Password, userExists.Creds.Password))
            {
                return userExists;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        string user = formCollection["User"], pass = formCollection["Password"];
        UserBLL bll = new UserBLL();
        if(bll.Authenticate(user,pass) != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

App.config (Business Layer) and Web.config (asp.net mvc) :

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="SQRASTConnectionString"
connectionString="Server=.\MSSQLSERVER;Database=DBAST; User Id=mydbuser;Password=mypassword;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Note: When I test this method with the console application it works fine (which I don't understand) and when I remove the connection string from web.config file it doesn't work (no connection string exception).

So my question is: Why do I have to provide my connection string to all the projects ?? 
And please help me fix the problem. Thanks

Comment: The dot-slash in server name looks ugly (./MSSQLSERVER). Remove it and try again.

Comment: Same error, that same connection string works on the console application, I don't know where is the difference :/

Comment: No difference at all. Was my fault I didn't catch the point that in a console the code works. Sorry.

Comment: It's ok thank you for your help :) But maybe you could tell me why I have to put the connection string in every project ???

Comment: can you connect to the SQL server with the management studio?

Comment: Yes I can, with the same user and password given in the connection string.